# Cross Platform .NET Application Packaging Using Mono?

Tags: .net, monodevelop, executable, packaging

I've started to get heavily into using MonoDevelop on Mac OSX and have a few applications that i need to package up into a single executable for both Windows and Mac OSX.

I know that MonoDevelop has mkbundle and a specific Mac OSX packager. However my experience with mkbundle hasnt been very good, it seems buggy and temperamental at the best of times on OSX and the specific OSX packager doesnt help me in the Windows situation.

So i guess my question is, what do other people use to build their executables. I've used Launch4J for Java before which was fantastic, so i'm looking for a similar solution on .NET.

Thanks